# line, tabs ,'s' counting problems and EOF Error

Tags: c, eof, charactercount

```
int main()
 {
 int c,nl,nt,Blanks;
 nl = 0;
 nt = 0;
 Blanks = 0;
 while ((c= getchar()) != '5'){
    if (c ='\n')
        nl++;
    if(c='\t')
        nt++;
    if(c = 's')
        Blanks ++;
 }

printf("No of lines is %d \n No of tabs %d \n and no of blanks %d \n",nl,nt,Blanks);

return 0;
```

Output:

```
 No of lines is 12 
 No of tabs 12 
 and no of blanks 12 

 RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5s)
```

The output is the number of any character entered and it doesn't distinguish between them at all.  Also, when I used the EOF to make the loop stop when it reached end of file, the loop didn't stop and the program continued to run.

Comment: `c ='\n'` --> `c == '\n'` and `'5'` --> `EOF` , `c = 's'` --> `c == ' '`

Comment: If you found one of our answers helpful you should mark it as your chosen answer using the check mark to the left of it. This will result in some extra reputation for the author, as well as a few points for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

In C, use `=` to assign, eg.

```
x = 5;
```

and use `==` to compare. eg.

```
if (x == 5) { /* do something */ }
```

If you use the wrong one, eg.

```
if (x = 5) { /* do something */ }
```

this this will result in assignment, rather than comparison. The expression `x = 5` will always be `true`, because `x` is non-zero, and non-zero is the same thing as `true` in C. That means that `/* do something */` will always be executed.

---

Also, `'5'` does not represent `EOF`, it represents the character `5`. You should replace `'5'` with `EOF`.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Besides this, it looks as though you are testing for spaces (`' '`) using `'s'`. This is wrong. `'s'` represents the character `s` in C. `' '` represents the `space` character in C.

---

And some advice: this is not directly related to the question, but since you're clearly new to C, I'll give you an important pointer.

Never use `if` statements without braces. eg.

```
if (/* condition */)
    /* do something */
```

Instead, use

```
if (/* condition */) {
    /* do something */
}
```

It's longer, I know, but later on you may decide to add another line of code, eg.

```
if (/* condition */)
    /* do something */
    /* do something else */
```

And you're going to be really confused about why `/* do something else */` is **always** executed, weather `/* condition */` is `true` or not.

Comment: the same problem arrised

Comment: @user3856638 If you would like, you can email me (anthropomorphic@mikefdorst.com) and I will help you. Once we figure out what the problem is I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if`s are wrong. You missed a second `=` in each `if`, now you are assigning the value to `c`, which results in `true`. Also, you can use `else if`, because the cases are exclusive.

```
int main()
{
  int c,nl,nt,Blanks;
  nl = 0;
  nt = 0;
  Blanks = 0;
  while ((c= getchar()) != '5'){
    if (c =='\n')
        nl++;
    else if(c=='\t')
        nt++;
    else if(c == 's')
        Blanks ++;
  }

  printf("No of lines is %d \n No of tabs %d \n and no of blanks %d \n",nl,nt,Blanks);

  return 0;
}
```